# How to stop elevation animating when changed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I found that when changing the elevation of a card widget, it will animate it to the new value. In the docs I found this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/elevation.html which told me this is the expected behaviour. However, I want it to change instantly and not animate. How can I remove the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `animationDuration` property to zero ,

```dart
  Material(
       ...
       animationDuration: Duration.zero,
     );
```

Use PhysicalModel  instead of Card widget

Comment: Where do I put this? I'm not using the Material widget anywhere and I tried wrapping some widgets here and there with it and setting the duration but it had no effect.

Comment: we don't know what kind of widgets are you using since you didn't show us any code :/

Comment: I'm using a Stack widget with a Positioned -> Container -> Card and it's the Card's elevation that I don't want to animate.